# Create bootable CD from installed system

Tags: boot, backup, data-recovery

I have Ubuntu Server 13 installed, with a somewhat complex arrangement of software RAID, LVM2 and partitions. It's the kind of installation that the standard Ubuntu boot CD can't cope with. One day the system ate itself but fortunately the initrd boot image had enough tools in it to repair the system.

Is there a way I can create a bootable CD/USB/whatever image from my installed system that incorporates all the kernel modules, raid config and so on from the actual machine - rather than a generic rescue disk.

I know there's a very similar question on here, but the method that I'd use relies on Remastersys which is ... no more.

Comment: Nope. You need to do this from an ISO and then do all the things you did to get your current system to that ISO. The best I can give you is this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679  (mine is marked as "11.04" but is command line so will also work for a server). Only thing you need to figure out is what commands you used for your install.